# Clarification on reading and writing files in C

Tags: c, input, output

I spent hours and hours trying to figure out how to read a string from an input file, process it and write vowels, consonants and numbers in 3 different output files. This is the code I have reached:

```
void discriminator(input, output1, output2, output3) {

    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u' || ) {
        fputs(string[i], output1);
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
    }
    else if (int string[i]) {
        fputs(string[i], output2);
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
    }
    else {
        fputs(string[i], output3);
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
    }
}

int main() {

    FILE *inFile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE *outVocali = fopen("outputVocali.txt", "w");
    FILE *outNumeri = fopen("outputNumeri.txt", "w");
    FILE *outConsonanti = fopen("outputConsonanti.txt", "w");

    char *string;
    char *fgets(string, EOF, inFile);
    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(string, EOF, inFile)) {
                discriminator(inFile, outVocali, outNumeri, outConsonanti);
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outVocali);
    fclose(outNumeri);
    fclose(outConsonanti);

    return 0;
}
```

This is what complier write:

esercizio.c:6:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
        ^

esercizio.c:6:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
               ^

esercizio.c:6:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
                            ^

esercizio.c:6:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
                                   ^

esercizio.c:6:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
                                                ^

esercizio.c:6:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || stri...
                                                       ^

esercizio.c:6:69: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
  ...== 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || st...
                                                       ^

esercizio.c:6:76: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
  ...'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || strin...
                                                           ^

esercizio.c:6:89: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
  ...== 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u' || ) {
                                                       ^

esercizio.c:6:96: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
  ...'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u' || ) {
                                                           ^

esercizio.c:6:109: error: expected expression
  ...'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u' || ) {
                                                                        ^

esercizio.c:7:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
        fputs(string[i], output1);
              ^

esercizio.c:7:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        fputs(string[i], output1);
                     ^

esercizio.c:8:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
        ^

esercizio.c:8:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
            ^

esercizio.c:8:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
                       ^

esercizio.c:8:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        i = i + sizeof(string[i]);
                              ^

esercizio.c:10:14: error: expected expression
    else if (int string[i]) {
             ^

esercizio.c:11:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
        fputs(string[i], output2);
              ^

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: what is your specific problem ?

Comment: When I compile the code, jump out errors regarding the variables. I do not know if I made mistakes, first of all about the pointers because invoking the procedure "discriminator" in the main the compiler tells me that string and i are not declared variables

Comment: @RiccardoTosti Please read any simple C tutorial after then you can solves max of those errors

Answer (score 0):

Is it your whole program? What are the #include lines? One issue I see is that `char *string` doesn't allocate memory. Also, the next line

```
while(fgets(stringa, EOF, inFile)) {
```

references nonexistent variable stringa.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>